# Combine Flash and Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I have a Flash application built with Adobe Flash CS5. Is there a way to integrate it into the Adobe Flex (I'm using FLash Builder 4)?

Why I'm asking: Adobe Flash seems to be the best way to import animation and graphics in the Flash application. At the same time, it looks like Flex is the best choice to make the GUI (buttons, lists, dialogs etc.) I'm making a game and so I need both. Also, would appreciate if somebody suggests an alternative for these.

Comment: i would try to avoid using flex for games (where fps is important). there are decent non-flex components out there for flash-only projects. eg http://www.minimalcomps.com/ or (for Stage3D) http://feathersui.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Flash is great for creating your assets on the timeline and exporting them to either a swf or a swc.

Flex doesn't care how you give it the assets, it all depends on which method is suitable for your application.

You can export assets in a swf and either embed at compile time (larger app swf), or load at runtime (smaller app swf, assets only available after loading).

You can also have the assets in a swc but these cannot be loaded at runtime, only embedded at compile time.

Using the term assets above, I'm referring to MovieClips on the stage using the timeline, you can also embed or load PNGs and JPGs as assets.